# Apache "httpd fullstatus" when connection limit exceeded

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm trying to dump "httpd fullstatus" to a log file at the exact moment when the connection limit has been exceeded and Apache stops accepting new connections. Unfortunately "httpd fullstatus" requires a free connection and thus will not work when Apache refuses new connections.

Is there a way to get the same information that "httpd fullstatus" returns without using any Apache connections or forcing Apache to ignore connection limit to complete this command? Thanks.